# Unrecognizable apk

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

Apk generated by android studio is not available for install inside phone memory.
When i Run'app' my application from android studio using USB with my phone (Samsung A3) it works fine. But when i generate apk file and transfer it to another phone (Samsung J7) file is locked. When i select apk file it toss "file lock" message. The app icon is not shown and instead there is icon of a paper with a lock on the left bottom of it.

There is no error in compile or anywhere else so i figure it might be for my faulty gradle. So i add the codes inside.

```
//build.gradle(project) content.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
        belong 
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()      
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
-------------------------------------------------------------
//build.gradle(module) content

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.games.appname"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.0.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13-beta-3'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    }
}
```

Comment: did you allow installation from 3rd party sources on your device ?

Comment: on your actual phone, have you tried doing this : http://www.inbox.com/article/how-do-enable-third-party-apps-on-android.html

Comment: You mean "Unknown source" switch in setting > security?
Yeah its on, it just dont recognize the file as apk!

Comment: that's very weird. some phones do have problems installing apk's like you've mentioned, try downloading an apk installer from the app store to see if that helps

Comment: I have tested with another phone, when i select the apk it ask that if its a Text or Video or ...

Comment: yeah, i think your device just doesn't know what to do with it. try downloading an apk installer from the appstore to help. goodluck :)

Comment: yeah i understand your frustration, sadly i dont really have a fix for you though